# Android : One background for two fragments

Tags: java, android, background

I try to make an app but I have an issue with the background.

[image: Schema image]

The above image shows what should look like the app. Every rectangle of color is a fragment and the red one already have the correct part of the background. But now I try to figure out how can i make the green rectangle background respect this rules :

- Image width needs to match parent
- The image needs to keep his ratio
- Image need to "stick" the bottom (in that way the upper part shows in the red rectangle won't appears in the green one)

In the green fragment I have a `ConstraintLayout`and an `ImageView` like above :

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ss_background_blur"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

The `@drawable/ss_background_blur` is my PNG image.

Thx

Comment: Why not set the background to the container of these three fragment?

Comment: Use Bottom Tabs for navigation buttons below the screen. Set background using xml. Keep background of your middle fragment as drawable...

Comment: Yes I think it'll be easier to can the app structure in order put the background in the container :) Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *Neo Shen* pointed out in the comments, the only thing you need to do is set the `background` property of the container element to the `drawable` resource (the image).

If you have an `Activity` which only contains three `Fragment` elements, then you can set the `background` of the main `Activity` layout.

You can see and clone a quick demo I put together here:

https://github.com/sipox11/full-background-android-app

This is the result:

[image: Demo App]

Note: I did it very quickly so obviously the tabs are not real tabs and the top bar is not a real nav bar, but you get the idea.

In this case the background image is actually below the tabs area, but if you want it to start on top of it, you can wrap the top and middle fragments within a `LinearLayout` and set the background image to that container.

Hope it helps, 
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Set the background of the rootlayout to green and add `android:layout_margin="2dp"` to the imageview .

Hope this helps.